# Passing a flag indicating all the chunks in a file are complete in ng-flow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js

I am new to flow and I am trying to figure out if there is way we can send a flag to indicate all the chunks in a given file are complete.

This is my html

```
    <div ng-controller="filesCtrl" flow-init=" config" flow-name="uploader.flow">
        <div class="drop" flow-drop ng-class="dropClass">
            <span class="btn" flow-btn><i class="icon icon-file"></i>Select File</span>
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-success" ng-click="upload()">Upload</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my app.js

```
    function filesCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.uploader = {};
    $scope.config = {
            target: 'api/check/Upload',
            permanentErrors: [404, 500, 501],
            maxChunkRetries: 1,
            chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
            simultaneousUploads: 4,
            singleFile: true,
            headers: { id: 5, source: 'flow_header' }
    }
    $scope.upload = function () {
        $scope.config = {
            query: { flowChunkComplete: $scope.uploader.flow.files[0].isComplete() },
        }
        $scope.uploader.flow.upload();
    }    
}
```

But query never gets populated with isComplete(), is there a way we can achieve this?